# how to add onclick event in renderCell of dataGrid mui components which is class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

> > below is my userlist.jsx component which show the user data on the table iam using mui component datagrid and i have added delete button  in the table using renderCell but it's doesnot work.

```
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
    { field: 'user', headerName: 'User', width: 170, renderCell: (params)=>{
        return(
            <div className='userlistuser'>
            <img className='userlistimage' src={params.row.avatar} alt="profile"/>
            {params.row.username}
            </div>
        )
    } },
    { field: 'email', headerName: 'Email', width: 190},
    {
      field: 'post',
      headerName: 'Post',
      width: 140,
    },
    {
        field:'Action',
        headerName:'Action',
        widht:150,
        renderCell:(params)=>{
            return(
                <>
                <Link to={"/user/"+ params.row.id}>
                <button className='userlistedit'>Edit</button>
                </Link>
>>after clicking this button i want to delete this particular user from the table.
<DeleteOutline className="userlistdelete" onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(params.row.id)}/>
                </>
            )
    
        }

    }

  ];

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
state={userdata:Userrows}

handleDelete = (id) =>{
    console.log(id);
}

 render(){
  return (
<div className='userlist'>
<DataGrid
        rows={this.state.userdata}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={7}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

*i have a delete button which should delete the data of the table
but as i click the delete button is throws error at console
'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleDelete')
*

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to have render cell to provide onClick event on MUI Data Grid :

```
  { field:"fundListMapped",headerName: "Funds Mapped" ,type: 'string', width:300 ,
  renderCell: (cellValues) => {
   
      return (
        <>
        <div>{displayList[0]},{displayList[1]},{displayList[2]}      
        <a href="#" onClick={(event) => {
  this.setActiveTab(event, cellValues);
}}>
        ...View Full List
         </a>
                       <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    onClick={(event) => {
      this.handleCellClick(event, cellValues);
    }}
  >
    Print
  </Button>
        </div>
        </>
        );
    }
    
}
```